# Clearing list from partial view with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list that is created by a javascript function. I have a separate function to reset the page, but it will not clear the list that was created. Any thoughts?

Javascript call to create the list:

```
$(function submit() {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#searchResults").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/TAPost',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (accts) {
                $("#rowHeaders").append('<tr><td>' + "Customer Name" + '</td><td>' + "     Customer SSN" + '</td><td>' + "     FHBOAT Account Number" + '</td><td>' +
                    "     Original Account Number" + '</td><td>' + "     Product Type" + '</td><tr>');
                $.each(accts, function (index, acct) {
                    $("#resultsTable").append('<tr><td>' + acct.CustomerName + '</td><td>' + "     " + acct.SSN + '</td><td>' + "     " + acct.FHAcctNumber + '</td><td>'
                        + "     " + acct.OriginalAcctNumber + '</td><td>' + "     " + acct.ProductType + '</td></tr>');
                });
                  }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Call to reset:

```
function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("LOB").style.borderColor = "";
    document.getElementById("LOB").style.borderColor = "";
    $('#resultsTable').empty();
    return false;
};
```

HTML:

```
<section id="searchResults">
    <h2>Search Results</h2>
    <table id="resultsTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="50">
        <thead id="rowHeaders"></thead>
   </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `resetForm`? What is "LOB" mentioned in `resetForm`? Are you sure your Ajax call is hitting the `success` block? That URL looks suspect to me. Also what list are you talking about? The DOM objects or some in-memory list of values?

Comment: The reset function is called from the partial view. The list is displayed in the html id="resultsTable". The submit function works fine.

Comment: What partial view? I guess what I'm trying to say is you haven't provided enough information to really get solid help yet.

Comment: The searchResults section is the last section within the partial view, the rest is 5 textboxes that the user uses to enter search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$('#resultsTable').empty();
```

You can use:

```
$('#resultsTable').html('');
```

Comment: Jose - I tried that too and it does not work? I have tried .hide(), .style = "hidden", etc.

Comment: If you want, please create an online demo on https://jsfiddle.net/ or some similar site and I will take a look